# How to calculate the slope of a line knowing two point not using division?

Tags: math, graphics

knowing two pints A(x0,y0) and B(x1,y1), how to calculate the slope of the line not using division?

Comment: Why do you not want to use division?

Comment: More of a maths questions rather than programming

Comment: If you mean the kind of math that a grammar school kid should be able to do, then yes, it's "math".

Comment: well, so can u solve this MATH problem ? do not use division, sin, cos ? @duffymo

Comment: Somebody gave you two acceptable answers below.  It's been a week - isn't that enough?

Comment: I've seen it before, and I've solved the problem, and u saw it, so, why are u here discussing this?

Answer (score 3):

You should probably ask this in a math forum or something of that sort. The slope is given by (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1) so if you don't want to use division, pick your points such that (x2 - x1) is 1.

You can also apply a log to the whole equation if that's an option: log(slope) = log(y2 - y1) - log(x2 - x1)

Comment: Math forum?  This is little more than grammar school algebra.

Comment: FWIW this is a valid question especially when writing code for a microprocessor that doesn't have hardware division.  The division operation therefore takes a relatively long time.
Your answer using LOG can be slightly modified to LOG base 2 which can be executed by shifting bits; when using fixed-point math this provides for a much faster calculation of slope.